# Error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 in my program android

Tags: java, android

I start to developpe in android, and I try to modify Snake code for including a call to browser for desplaying web page, when i execute my application it shows the page in the brwser, but the problem when i come back to snake application it shows message that the application has stoped unexpectedly, and the logCat show anthe exception below

```
02-19 01:06:50.920: W/dalvikvm(3394): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4015a760)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at com.example.android.snake.SnakeView.updateSnake(SnakeView.java:448)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at com.example.android.snake.SnakeView.update(SnakeView.java:403)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at com.example.android.snake.SnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.java:335)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at com.example.android.snake.SnakeView.onKeyDown(SnakeView.java:278)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2387)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:4569)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1113)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1113)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1113)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1113)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1260)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2231)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1648)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRoot.java:2730)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2703)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1958)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-19 01:06:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3394):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 01:08:07.450: D/A
```

Comment: It's telling you that you're trying to access an ArrayList beyond its bounds.

Comment: The exception is self-explanatory `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

Comment: The code I added is in the onCreate function

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.vogella.de"));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       
      
         try 
            { 
                    startActivity(intent); 
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
            }

Comment: before i add this lines in the methode on Create it work normally

Answer (score 11):

I think it's quite clear, here

> at com.example.android.snake.SnakeView.updateSnake(SnakeView.java:448)

you are accessing an `ArrayList` that has been instantiated as `new ArrayList(0)`, quite straightforward if you at least read the error.

`ArrayList` objects are meant to automatically resize, but if you don't place anything in a zero-sized array list then you get this error.

Answer (score 7):

You have an `ArrayList` with 0 elements in them. and in the `SnakeView` class in the `updateSnake()` method on line 448, you try to access the arraylist at index 0. At index 0 is the first element of you `ArrayList`, but if it is empty there is no element at index 0. So you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`